# How to get the user ranking data of Stack Exchange using the API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I want to get the user ranking data on the "Users" page of Stack Exchange (see the following figure), but do not find relevant APIs implementing such goals. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s88Yc.png)

Comment: Head to data.stackexchange.com
Check this interesting link: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries

Comment: Did you get it figured it out?

Comment: @ashleedawg Following UdayrajDeshmukh's comment, I found this link: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile