# How to get the Stack Overflow rank of a user using the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I want to create a React component that fetches data from Stack Overflow of a specific user. I haven't had any issues to get: reputation, answers, badges, etc. using [Stack Exchange API v2.3](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) but I'm having a hard time trying to implement an API that will return the current ranking as shown [in this Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile) and [in the Stack Exchange reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow).

Almost 4 years ago a user asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092011/how-to-get-the-user-ranking-data-of-stack-exchange-using-the-api) without any response. Why is that? Is it impossible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible via the API. You can use two other "tricks", though (both must be done server-side because the sites return CORS headers):

1. **Scrape** the `/leagues` page. Call the endpoint:

   ```
   GET /leagues/1/<type>/<site>/<YYYY-MM-DD>/<userId>
   ```

   (e.g. `/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2021-01-01/10607772`), look for the `.highlight .number` selector and get the inner text. If you want just the number, remember to remove `#` in the front of the result.

   However, the probem is that all league URLs exist in [`robots.txt`](https://stackexchange.com/robots.txt), so if you make too many requests, you might be rate-limited.
2. Fetch the information from Data Explorer. Call:

   ```
   POST /query/run/<siteId>/<queryId>/97298
   ```

   (for [the query you've linked](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile), the site id is `1` and the query id `6772`).

   - If `running` exists in the returned JSON and is `true`, then using `job_id` call:

     ```
     POST /query/job/<job_id>
     ```

     every 1500 milliseconds ([that's what Stack Exchange uses](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Scripts/query.js#L163)) until `resultSets` is present in the response.
   - If not, then look directly for `resultSets`.

   Here's a sample value of that property:

   ```json
   [
       {
           "columns": [
               {
                   "name": "Id",
                   "type": "Number"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Ranking",
                   "type": "Number"
               },
               {
                   "name": "Percentile",
                   "type": "Number"
               }
           ],
           "rows": [
               [
                   10607772,
                   65137,
                   0.0586909706892046
               ]
           ],
           "messagePosition": 0,
           "truncated": false
       }
   ]
   ```

   Note that the results are only updated [every Sunday](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). You might get rate-limited as well if you make too many requests in a short time period.